# Nuxt $vuetify.theme.dark reset when i change page

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm using **Nuxt.js v2.12.2 with Vuetify**.
I installed Vuetify during the initial configuration of the new project.

I want to build a static website with some functionality like **change the theme from dark to light**.

So I added a switch in my default layout to change this property: $vuetify.theme.dark

Here's my code for the switch:

```
<v-switch v-model="$vuetify.theme.dark" />
```

I even tried in this way but is the same:

```
<v-switch @click="$vuetify.theme.dark = !$vuetify.theme.dark" />
```

When I click on the switch the property change correcly.
But if I change page or I reload, it goes back to his previous value.

**How do I change this property so that it stays that way for the session?
Do I need to save it somewhere?**

Here's the code inside nuxt.config.js:

```
 vuetify: {
customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
theme: {
  themes: {
    dark: {
      primary: colors.blue.darken2,
      accent: colors.grey.darken3,
      secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
      info: colors.teal.lighten1,
      warning: colors.amber.base,
      error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
      success: colors.green.accent3
    },
    light: {
      primary: '#3f51b5',
      secondary: '#b0bec5',
      accent: '#8c9eff',
      error: '#b71c1c',
    },
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Suggested by Art Mary, one additional thing you need to do is store the setting in Localstorage and then on the application load, fetch the setting from there. So basically:

1. Watch for the `goDark` property.
2. On change of `goDark` property store the value in Localstorage.
3. In the component containing v-app, on mounted (`onMounted`) fetch the value from there `localStorage.getItem('[your key for dark property]')`, if there is any, use it or assign default.

Answer (score 3):

First of all in Vuetify config file you need to add this property:

```
dark: true/false
```

the configuration should now look like this:

```js
theme: {
  dark: true,
  themes: {
    dark: {
      primary: colors.blue.darken2,
      accent: colors.grey.darken3,
      secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
      background: '#34358e'
    },
    light: {
     primary: '#3f51b5',
     secondary: '#b0bec5',
     accent: '#8c9eff',
     error: '#b71c1c',
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your Layout in the v-app component you have to bind a method

it look like this:

```html
<v-app :dark="setTheme">
 <v-container>
  <v-switch v-model="goDark"></v-switch>
 </v-container>
</v-app>
```

and in your script tag add goDark in data and setTheme as a computed property.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    goDark: false,
  }),
  computed: {
    setTheme() {
      if (this.goDark === true) {
        return (this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true);
      } else {
        return (this.$vuetify.theme.dark = false);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

It should work now.

Comment: Unfortunately, even in this way, the theme becomes light when I change or reload the page

Comment: Can you create a demo link from the problem? @L.Gangemi

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it the way below.

#### 1. Set switcher

`layouts/default.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn
      class="px-1"
      min-width="0px"
      icon
      :color="$vuetify.theme.dark ? 'yellow' : 'indigo'"
      @click="switchTheme()"
    >
      <v-icon>mdi-theme-light-dark</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$vuetify.theme.dark = this.$store.state.darkMode
  },
  methods: {
    switchTheme() {
      this.$store.commit('SWITCH_DARK')
      this.$vuetify.theme.dark = this.$store.state.darkMode
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

#### 2. Save dark mode state in Vuex store

`store/index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
  darkMode: false,
})

export const mutations = {
  SWITCH_DARK(state) {
    state.darkMode = !state.darkMode
  },
}
```

#### 3. Make store persistent at page update

Install [vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist):

```
npm install --save vuex-persist
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for retrieving dark mode after app reload:

```
mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$vuetify.theme.dark = localStorage.getItem('dark') === 'true'
    }, 200)
}
```

For switching theme in runtime:

```
computed: {
   mode: {
    set(theme) {
       this.$vuetify.theme.dark = theme === 'dark'
       localStorage.setItem('dark', theme === 'dark')
     },
    get() {
       return this.$vuetify.theme.dark ? 'dark' : 'light'
    }
   }
 }
```